# SSD and HDD transfer-rates impossibly high

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, windows-8.1, transfer-rate

Sometimes when I transfer a file from my SSD (Samsung 840 pro) to the same SSD, the transfer-rate is 800+ MBps, which should impossible from a SATA6 drive. Also, my HDD performs at 300+ MBps, again impossible from a WD Black drive.

How can these transfer-rates be explained?

Answer (score 4):

Cached reads and writes.

In order to get accurate results you probably need to transfer more data then your system has memory and ensure you sync the filesystem afterwards (not sure how you do this under Windows)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by transfer? If that is just a move in the same partition then it takes almost instantly to transfer the file to the new location. If the file is small then after NTFS cached the file it may report to the program that the operation was done before it is really copy to the new location, so that the program don't have to wait. In that case the speed also not real

You can see that sometimes copying a file to a flash USB formatted with NTFS then for the first seconds the speed burst out 50-60MB/s which maybe 10 times it's normal write speed, but then the speed and percent copied stop counting for a while before the speed becomes real